# Fade color of div to opacity as user scrolls down the window JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fadein

I have a header div with an id of "#box" that I have fixed at the top as my page so it stays there as you scroll down the page. What I currently have is as the user scrolls down, the background color of the header div changes from it's opaque state to 50% transparency using{ window.pageYOffset > 50 } and back to it's original transparency if the header is back at the top. So it basically goes from one solid state to another and I would like to find a way for it fade from its starting 50% transparency to its opaque state with a fade in effect using Javascript. Below I have the original code for my original scenario and below is my attempt to create the fade in effect but am totally stuck. It is not working at all;nothing happens. Would it easier using Jquery?

Original Scenario:

window.onscroll = scroll;

```
function scroll() {
    var header=document.getElementById("header1");

    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
    console.log("Change Opacity now");
      document.getElementById("header1").style.backgroundColor="rgba(38, 28, 63, 1.0)";
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("header1").style.backgroundColor="rgba(38, 28, 63, 0.5)";

    }

}
```

Fade-In Attempt:

window.onscroll = scroll;

```
function scroll() {
    var header=document.getElementById("box");

    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    if(window.pageYOffset > 0){
        var color = [38, 28, 63].join(',') + ',', 
         transparency = 1,
         element = this, 
         timeout = setInterval(function(){
             if(transparency < 0){ 
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(' + color + (transparency -= 0.015) + ')';
        } else {
            clearInterval(timeout);
        }
    }, 40);
```

});

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If it does run and the color changes but doesn't transition, an easy way of achieving the transition is by adding the css attrib 'transition: background 1s;' to the header.

If its not that, could you please elaborate what's not working? 
By that i mean, is the functioning not getting called? etc...

Comment: awesome man! thanks a lot...this saved me a bunch of unnecessary JS

Comment: Np. Oh and don't forget that transition is browser specific so uh... Add the other browser versions for Mozilla and IE and others xD

-webkit-transition, -moz-transition,-o-transition, transition. Something like that haha

Comment: hmmm..for some reason, even with the vendor prefix for mozilla, the tansparency is not there when the page loads yet works fine in chrome...I even used what you mentioned above...is it because I'm using RGBA but even then, that is supported by mostly all broswers